# Dropdown list in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

i've a view. in the view i've months field(nvarchar type in database) :

```
         @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.rent_month,               
         (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.months)
```

i've a method in a model class (PostManager) to generate months list like:

```
          public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetMyMonthList()
         {
           return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames
            .Select(m => new SelectListItem() { Text = m, Value = m });
         }
```

i get  months in get action  by :

```
     public ActionResult Create()
    {
       PostModel p = new PostModel();

     ViewBag.months = pm.GetMyMonthList();
       return View(p);
     }
```

in my Model my month attributes:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You Must Select a Month.")]
    [Display(Name = "Select Rent Month")]
    public string rent_month { get; set; }
```

in the post action:

```
      public ActionResult Create(PostModel p)
       {
         if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
             post post = new Models.DB.post();
                 post.rent_month = p.rent_month;  
               db.posts.AddObject(post);
                    db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

it generates month in the dropdownlist correctly.But after submit the form it gives error:

**The ViewData item that has the key 'rent_month' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'**

now what is the solution for this error... thanks in advance...

Comment: Please show your model and controller.

Comment: Could you please show the action you are submitting your form to in the controller?

Comment: Is that your entire Create action? Please show the parts of the action that return views.

Comment: i've edit my question. please check out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is happening because in your post action you are not populating the ViewBag again. Make sure you set `ViewBag.months = pm.GetMyMonthList();` in your controller POST action similar to what you have done in GET action.

Better solution would be to have a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> MonthList` property as part of the PostModel. Instead of loading the months from ViewBag you can access it directly by the MonthList property

In the PostModel

```
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> MonthList
    {
        get
        {
            return pm
                .GetMonthList()
                .Select(a => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = a.Id,
                    Text = a.MonthText
                })
                .ToList();
        }
    }
```

Then in the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.rent_month, Model.MonthList)
```

**After EDIT to the question**

Your PostModel class should be like this. I have moved your GetMyMonthList() implementation out of the PostManager class.

```
    public class PostModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "You Must Select a Month.")]
        [Display(Name = "Select Rent Month")]
        public string rent_month { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> MonthList
        {
            get
            {
                return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames
                 .Select(m => new SelectListItem() { Text = m, Value = m });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i've add monthlist as a attribute of postmodel and in the view i've add your view code. it gives error in the view page. error code: CS1928

Comment: my implementation of public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> MonthList is just an example. It is a property not a method attribute. You will need to modify it depending your implementation. see my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class PostModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "You Must Select a Month.")]
        [Display(Name = "Select Rent Month")]
        public string rent_month { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> MonthList
        {
            get
            {
                return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames
                 .Select(m => new SelectListItem() { Text = m, Value = m });
            }
        }
    }
```